# How to modify results generated by Yii2 createCommand() function

Tags: php, sql, database, yii2, dataprovider

I have a SQL query in my controller. The results have two fields: `id_person` and `name_person`. Then I use `ArrayDataProvider` to show the results in a `GridView`:

```
return new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => Yii::$app->getDb()->createCommand($mySql)->queryAll()
]);
```

But the id of the **update button** is not `id_person`. It has an id auto generated.

So I have a data provider with the fields: `id`, `id_person` and `name_person`. I need to replace `id` by `id_person`.

I can resolve it in my view file under the action of update button but it could be better to resolve it in my controller.

I checked the [API Documentation for Yii 2.0](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command) but It doesn't help me.

Comment: why you are not using a sqlDataProvider ??

Comment: Oh, I never used it. I will check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure [`ArrayDataProvider::$key`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider#$key-detail) property to specify column with record ID:

```
return new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => Yii::$app->getDb()->createCommand($mySql)->queryAll(),
    'key' => 'id_person',
]);
```